# Check if an IP is contained in a set of ranges?

Tags: java, subnet

Does anyone know of a clean way to check if an IP is contained in a set of ranges?

I'm getting a response that looks like this:

```
"ipRange": "10.12.0.0/16,10.80.0.0/15,10.83.0.0/16,10.101.0.0-10.103.255.255,10.108.0.0/16,10.121.0.0/16,10.123.0.0/16,10.127.0.0/16,10.129.0.0/16,10.131.0.0/16,10.133.0.0/16,10.135.0.0-10.139.255.255,10.208.0.0/14,10.215.0.0/16,10.218.0.0/15,10.233.0.0/16,172.17.128.0-172.19.255.255,172.24.0.0/15,192.168.0.0/16"
```

And I need to see if an IP is in any of those works. The ones with "slash" notation should be straight forward, but what about the ranges where they have "-"?

Comment: its have different networks, and subnets

Comment: This seems like a matter of parsing the result string, translating the IPs to pure numerical 32 bit numbers, identifying the range for each set of IPs, and finally using a comparator that will check the target IP against the IP ranges - in 33 bit number format.

Comment: Have you tried the following library (don't know if it could help)? https://github.com/edazdarevic/CIDRUtils

Comment: It looks like [`SubNetUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.html) from Apache Commons / Net is what you need

Comment: **See also [Convert `IP` address range to `CIDR` in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64513460/8740349)**

Answer (score 2):

An IPv4 address is nothing else than a unsigned int32. The easy way to check whether IP address A with network mask X is in subnet B with network mask Y:

1. convert A to uint32
2. convert B to uint32
3. convert Y to uint32
4. if (A & Y) == (B & Y) then yes

Answer (score 0):

I've commented the code below. Basically, I split the "ipRanges" into distinct ipAddresses or ipAddressRanges by looking for ",". Then test the given ip to each of those to see if it is good.

```
String ipRange = "10.12.0.0/16,10.80.0.0/15,10.83.0.0/16,10.101.0.0-10.103.255.255,10.108.0.0/16,10.121.0.0/16,10.123.0.0/16,10.127.0.0/16,10.129.0.0/16,10.131.0.0/16,10.133.0.0/16,10.135.0.0-10.139.255.255,10.208.0.0/14,10.215.0.0/16,10.218.0.0/15,10.233.0.0/16,172.17.128.0-172.19.255.255,172.24.0.0/15,192.168.0.0/16";


public IPAddressTest() {
    String ipToTest = "10.101.0.0";
    System.out.println(String.format("[%s] is in range (%b)", ipToTest, isInRange(ipToTest)));
}

private Boolean isInRange(String ipToTest) {
    String[] ranges = ipRange.split(",");

    for (String _range : ranges) {
        String range = _range.indexOf("/") > -1 ? _range.substring(0, _range.indexOf("/")) : _range; // cut off the /xx if it exists
        boolean test = test(ipToTest, range);
        if (test) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private Boolean test(String ipToTest, String ipRange) {
    String[] ranges = ipRange.split("-"); // Do we have a range or just a single ip
    String loRange = ranges[0]; // grab the first
    String hiRange = ranges.length > 1 ? ranges[1] : null; // If there a range grab the top end, else nothing

    if (hiRange == null) { // if a single ip, just do a string compare
        return ipToTest.equals(loRange);
    } else { // if a range then make sure each part is between the min and max
        String[] partsToTest = ipToTest.split("\\."); // get each part of the ip
        String[] partsLoRange = loRange.split("\\."); // get each part of the ip
        String[] partsHiRange = hiRange.split("\\."); // get each part of the ip
        int test = 0; // this will be our litmus test. if it = 15 when we are done, then each part is good, 63 of ipv6
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // change 4 to 6 for ipv6
            int value = Integer.parseInt(partsToTest[i]); //get the int
            int lo = Integer.parseInt(partsLoRange[i]); //get the int
            int hi = Integer.parseInt(partsHiRange[i]); //get the int
            if (value >= lo && value <= hi) { // if we have a good value, set the bit on 'test'
                test += Math.pow(2, i);
            }
        }
        if (test == 15) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new IPAddressTest();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like you're handling CIDR masks correctly. An entry like `10.12.0.0/16` already matches 65,535 addresses.