# Converting CIDR notation into IP range without other library

Tags: java, binary, byte, subnet

I want to find the IP range from CIDR.
For example, I input "192.168.1.1/24".
How do I calculate the IP range in Java?

I only can change the IP address and subnet mask to byte[].
But I don't know how to merge them.
This is my code.

```
String str = "192.168.1.1/24";
String[] cidr = str.split("/");
String[] buf = cidr[0].split(".");
byte[] ip = new byte[] { 
                (byte)Integer.parseInt(buf[0]), (byte)Integer.parseInt(buf[1]),(byte)Integer.parseInt(buf[2]), (byte)Integer.parseInt(buf[3])
};

int mask = 0xffffffff << (32 - Integer.parseInt(cidr[1]));
        int value = mask;
        byte[] subnet = new byte[] {
                (byte)(value >>> 24), (byte)(value >> 16 & 0xff), (byte)(value >> 8 & 0xff), (byte)(value & 0xff)
        };
```

Comment: What value(s) do you expect to be returned when `192.168.1.1/24` is mapped to a range of IPs?

Comment: First thing you need to do is fix the regex, because `.` has special meaning: `cidr[0].split("\\.");`

Comment: For the other way around, **See [Convert `IP` address range to `CIDR` in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64513460/8740349)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you need to do is fix the regex, because `.` has special meaning: `cidr[0].split("\\.");`

Then, to build the from and to addresses of the IP range, using bitwise AND, OR, and NOT:

```java
byte[] from = new byte[4];
byte[] to = new byte[4];
for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
    from[i] = (byte) (ip[i] & subnet[i]);
    to[i] = (byte) (ip[i] | ~subnet[i]);
}
```

Finally, print the result:

```java
System.out.printf("%d.%d.%d.%d - %d.%d.%d.%d%n",
        Byte.toUnsignedInt(from[0]), Byte.toUnsignedInt(from[1]),
        Byte.toUnsignedInt(from[2]), Byte.toUnsignedInt(from[3]),
        Byte.toUnsignedInt(to[0]), Byte.toUnsignedInt(to[1]),
        Byte.toUnsignedInt(to[2]), Byte.toUnsignedInt(to[3]));
```

*Output*

```
192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.255
```

---

*FYI:* The code fails for `/0` because to `mask` value ends up wrong. I'll leave that as an exercise for you to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

[The open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) will do this in a polymorphic manner for both IPv4 and IPv6.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

```java
IPAddress addr = new IPAddressString("192.168.1.1/24").getAddress().toPrefixBlock();
System.out.println(addr.getLower() + " - " + addr.getUpper());
```

Output:

```
192.168.1.0/24 - 192.168.1.255/24
```